# How to use QMutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex, qmutex

I'm newbie to Qt and I'm looking for multi-threading in Qt.
As I learned in [Qt Documents](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-starting.html), I defined two class for two thread:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>

class thread_a : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit thread_a(QObject *parent = 0);
    int counter;

protected:
    void run();
};
```

And in CPP file:

```
#include "thread_a.h"

thread_a::thread_a(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    counter=0;
}

void thread_a::run()
{
    counter++;
}
```

Second thread class is same, but with `counter--` in `run()` method.
Then I run this two threads from `main.ccp`.

Now my question:
How can I share `counter` in `thread_a` and `thread_b` using `QMutex`?

Comment: **You don't need a mutex in this case.** You seem to have 2 separate classes for each thread, as suggested by `class thread_a` declaration. This means that when both classes are instantiated, each would have it's own copy of `int counter;` and decreasing the `counter` of one object will not affect the `counter` of the other.

Comment: Thanks @karlphillip, you are right. But if i want share `counter` with both `thread_a` and `thread_b` what u suggest (using `QMutex` just for educational purpose)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to get problems with QThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084110/trying-to-get-problems-with-qthread)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of having the data within a thread, move the data outside the thread, protect it and then access it from both threads.

The following is a sketch, of what you could do:

```
class Counter
{
  public:
    Counter():mMutex(),mCounter(0){}
    int inc()
    {
      QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
      return mCounter++;
    }
    int dec()
      QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
      return mCounter--;
    }
  private:
    QMutex mMutex;
    int mCounter;
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Counter)
};

class ThreadA : public QThread
{
  public:
    ThreadA(Counter* ctr);
  /* ... */
};

class ThreadB : public QThread
{
  public:
    ThreadB(Counter* ctr);
  /* ... */
};
```

The construct of `Counter` is often referred to as a [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29), from Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> In concurrent programming, a monitor is an object or module intended to be used safely by more than one thread. The defining characteristic of a monitor is that its methods are executed with mutual exclusion. That is, at each point in time, at most one thread may be executing any of its methods. This **mutual exclusion greatly simplifies reasoning about the implementation of monitors compared to reasoning about parallel code that updates a data structure**.

In this specific case, a more efficient construct would be [`QAtomicInt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicint.html).
This gains atomicity from its use of special CPU instructions.
This is a low level class that could be used to implement other threading constructs.

---

**Edit - Complete Example**

Using threads with shared state correctly is not trivial. You may want to consider using Qt signals/slots with queued connections or other message based systems.

Alternatively, other programming languages such as Ada support Threads and Monitors (protected objects) as native constructs.

Here is a complete working example.
This is only sample code, don't use `QTest::qSleep` in real code.

**objs.h**

```
#ifndef OBJS_H
#define OBJS_H

#include <QtCore>

class Counter
{
    public:
        Counter(int init);
        int add(int v);
    private:
        QMutex mMutex;
        int mCounter;
        Q_DISABLE_COPY(Counter)
};

class CtrThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        CtrThread(Counter& c, int v);
        void stop();
    protected:
        virtual void run();
    private:
        bool keeprunning();
        Counter& mCtr;
        int mValue;
        bool mStop;
        QMutex mMutex;
};

#endif
```

**objs.cpp**

```
#include "objs.h"

Counter::Counter(int i):
    mMutex(),
    mCounter(i)
{}

int Counter::add(int v)
{
    QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
    return mCounter += v;
}

///////////////////////////////////////

CtrThread::CtrThread(Counter& c, int v):
    mCtr(c),
    mValue(v),
    mStop(false),
    mMutex()
{}

void CtrThread::stop()
{
    QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
    mStop = true;
}

void CtrThread::run()
{
    while(keeprunning())
    {
        mCtr.add(mValue);
    }
}

bool CtrThread::keeprunning()
{
    QMutexLocker ml(&mMutex);
    return ! mStop;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QTest>
#include "objs.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Initalising";

    Counter ctr(0);
    CtrThread thread_a(ctr, +1);
    CtrThread thread_b(ctr, -1);

    qDebug() << "Starting Threads";

    thread_a.start();
    thread_b.start();

    for (int i = 0; i != 15; ++i)
    {
        qDebug() << "Counter value" << ctr.add(0);
        QTest::qSleep(1000);
    }

    qDebug() << "Stopping Threads";

    thread_a.stop();
    thread_b.stop();
    thread_a.wait();
    thread_b.wait();

    qDebug() << "Finished";
    return 0;
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT=core testlib
HEADERS=objs.h
SOURCES=test.cpp objs.cpp
```

Compile and run, you will see the value being printed, sample output:

```
Initalising
Starting Threads
Counter value 0
Counter value 11057
Counter value 28697
Counter value 50170
Counter value 60678
Counter value 73773
Counter value 84898
Counter value 96441
Counter value 118795
Counter value 135293
Counter value 146107
Counter value 158688
Counter value 169886
Counter value 201203
Counter value 212983
Stopping Threads
Finished
```

Comment: Hey @skyhisi thanks for great solution... but I'm looking for `QMutex` just for education purpose. I want to learn multi-threading in Qt step-by-step. Can u give me a simple implementation using QMutex (for sharing `counter` on two thread)

Answer (score 4):

OK, special thanks to @skyhisi for great solution for a real project.

I read @skyhisi post and more articles about QMutex and sharing variables. For education purpose i implemented a simple/clear sample of QMutex usage for sharing variable (this case `counter`).

```
class thread_a : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    thread_a(QMutex*, int*);
    void shutdown();

private:
    QMutex* mutex;
    int* counter;
    bool isShutdownRequested;

protected:
    void run();
};
```

and  in `thread_a.cpp` file:

```
thread_a::thread_a(QMutex * m, int* i)
{
    counter=i;
    isShutdownRequested=false;
    mutex=m;
}

void thread_a::run()
{
    isShutdownRequested=false;
    forever{
        //lock mutex for changing in shared variable
        mutex->lock();
        *counter=*counter+1;
        mutex->unlock();

        if(isShutdownRequested)
            break;
    }
}

void thread_a::shutdown()
{
    isShutdownRequested=true;
}
```

In `myMainWindow::RunThreads(bool bl)` slot:

```
int cnt=0;
QMutex mu;
thread* a=new thread_a(&mu, &cnt);
thread* b=new thread_b(&mu, &cnt);
a.start();
b.start();
```

In `myMainWindow::~myMainWindow()` deconstructor:

```
a->shutdown();
b->shutdown();
```

Thanks again @skyhisi

Answer (score 1):

I write a simple example referenced to the "help" of QMutex, in which two threads change a same number (as a Monitor). It also ref S.M.Mousavi's code.
Here is code:

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "method.h"

int aNum=0;
QMutex aMutex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int *p_no= &aNum;
    QMutex *p_Mu = &aMutex;

    method mThread1(p_Mu, p_no);
    method mThread2(p_Mu, p_no);

    mThread1.name = "one";
    mThread2.name = "two";

    mThread1.start();
    mThread2.start();

   return a.exec();
}
```

// method.h

```
#ifndef METHOD_H
#define METHOD_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QMutex>


class method: public QThread
{
public:
    method(QMutex *mu, int *nu);
    void run();
    void method1();
    void method2();
    QString name;

private:
    int *number;
    QMutex *myMutex;
};

#endif // METHOD_H
```

//method.cpp
    #include "method.h"

```
method::method(QMutex *mu, int *nu)
{
    myMutex = mu;
    number = nu;
}


void method:: run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if(this->name == "one" )
        {
            this->method1();
        }
        else
        {
            this->method2();
        }
    }
}

void method::method1()
{
    myMutex->lock();
    *number += 1;
    qDebug()<<*number<<"---"<<this->name;
    myMutex->unlock();
}

void method ::method2()
{
    myMutex->lock();
    *number -= 1;
    qDebug()<<*number<<"---"<<this->name;
    myMutex->unlock();
}
```